# Python - How to increase accuracy of decimals?

Tags: python, module, floating-point, decimal

I'm writing a program where I need to pass in very accurate decimal representations of fractions (i.e. accurate to over 200 decimal places). However simply telling python to include more decimal places (using %.50f, for instance) often simply adds a bunch of 0s to the ends of certain decimals.

Is there a way to get python to display accurately an arbitrary number of  decimal places for a fraction? Do I need to install a package/module?

Comment: BigNumbers, BigDecimals, etc.? No idea what they are called in Python, but I am pretty sure Python has them. They allow you to define numbers with an almost inifinite amount of decimal places without losing precision.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.7 and above can do the following,

Using the [Decimal Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) from the python standard libraries by using `from decimal import *` and do this:

```
from decimal import *
with localcontext() as context:
    context.prec = #your_precision_here
    print(Decimal(#calculation_here))
```

Comment: Decimal I believe can do unlimited precision, because it does the same thing as the big numbers, so it can virtually have an unlimited precision

Comment: you should change 'is context' to 'as context'.  I would edit it, but its too small an edit to be allowed

Comment: Also, `print(decimal(#calculation_here))` should be `print(Decimal(#calculation_here))`, capital D.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), which is included with Python. It can show the *exact* decimal representation of any value stored in a float or decimal variable.

This is not quite the same as showing arbitrarily many decimal places for a fraction, but see if it meets your needs.